# update_post_meta does not work

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have meta box in my custom post type where I receive data from a front end form. The issue is that somewhere in this functions, something goes wrong and the data changed in admin edit panel does not apply to the post (update_post_meta does not get his job done I guess) Here is my code:

```
// HANDLER FOR THE FORM AND SAVING THE RIGHT DATA
<?php elseif(isset($_POST['test'])){ 
     $location = $_POST['_location'];
     $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    =>   $_POST['title'],
        'post_content'  =>   $_POST['description'],
        'post_status'   =>   'pending',          
        'post_type' =>   'eventstest'       
        );

        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        add_post_meta($pid, 'location', $location, true);
}

do_action('save_post', 'eg_save_events_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post'); 


// ADD THE META BOX
function add_events_metaboxes() { 
   add_meta_box('wpt_events_location', 'Event Location', 'wpt_events_location', 'eventstest', 'side', 'default');}

//DISPLAING META BOXES
function wpt_events_location() { 
global $post;

echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' . 
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

$_location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true);

echo '<input type="text" name="_location" value="' . $_location  . '" />';}


//SAVING AND UPDATE META FIELDS
function eg_save_events_location( $post_id ){

if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return;
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return;
if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
{
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
}
else
{
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;
}

$mydata = $_POST['_location'];
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', $mydata);}

add_action('save_post', 'eg_save_events_location', 1, 2); // save the custom fields once again in functions.php too
```

Comment: You should probably use $post_id in update_post_meta instead of $post->ID.

Comment: That does not work too.

Comment: Have you tried logging so you know appropriate functions are being run?

Comment: I know that data is beeing displayed in that metabox in admin editor. The only problem is when trying to update that data and nothing's happen. Did I answer the question correctly?

Comment: Is there something with getting the post ID with function hooked to 'edit-post' action? And then 'update-post-meta' on 'save- post' action again?

Comment: New update. Removed the check in function eg_save_events_location. Function now have only `$mydata = $_POST['_location'];
update_post_meta($post_id, 'location', $mydata);`
Now after 'Update post' button, post_meta can't be accessed via get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I removed all the wp_nonce fields everything is working slightly. As far as I can remember, their job is to prevent sending requests from undesireable places and some actions. I guess I can't make a proper nonce verification.